# I need a pattern for applying some validations on an object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, validation, design-patterns

I'm developing a validation helper class which will apply some validation rules on an instance of *application* object.
I found questions about *Hibernate Validator*, but what about C#?

Comment: Did you check [nhibernate validator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate-validator)?

Comment: @FredrikMörk >> no I didn't, I will and reply back, thanks

Comment: It's powerful, but somehow complicated and needs lot of reading :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my current project we are using this Framwork: http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

It can be perfectly used with the Repository- and Specification-Pattern along with the Entity Framework. Look here to find informations about those... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175/repository-pattern-tutorial-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

As a best practice, you should declare validation rules onto your models/entities using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation` - **this would not bake the implementation of the validation** which is always good.

Then using a validation framework with this is not a difficult choice and depends on other technologies that you use. For example, if you use MVC then it has a built-in mechanism, or if you use EF then it will do that for you.

## Edit

Examples:

public class NursingTreatment 
    {

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
    public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "This field may not be longer than 500 characters.")]
    public string LongText{ get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Annotations can only be used if the user is not allow to change validation rules during runtime...

Comment: True, but I am talking about 99% of cases where rules are **part of the domain** - hence does not change.

Comment: Well it is not really 99% percent. At least the Industry I am working on... ;-)

Comment: I know what you mean. But now that I am more mature in analysis I find out that (dont know about your case) a lot of dynamic validation requirements are in fact poor analysis of the domain.

Comment: @Aliostad, could please give an example for your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The answer may depend on the framework. For instance, if using WPF then you can implement the IDataErrorInfo interface, or alternatively throw exceptions and use ValidatesOnExceptions in your bindings.